# How To Separate UUids For Jquery-Sortable

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, uuid

I want to use jquery-ui sortable method for my larave project. When i was separate my `<tr>` rows with id, there is no problem.

Example;

`<tr id="item-1">`

But if I want to use uuids instead of id my tr row becoming like this:

```
<tr id="item-b20s0b82-dc01-4e9a-a7a6-cd60ff5f9165">
```

So, if i try to use like this way, it gives me error. I'm using "-" to separate but uuids also have "-"

How can i fix this?
Thanks...

UPDATE:

index.blade part of the my table(trying to sortable)

```
<tbody id="sortable">
                @foreach($data['blogs'] as $blogs)
                    <tr id="item-{{$blogs->id}}">
                        <td>{{$loop->iteration}}</td>
                        <td><img width="100" src="/images/blogs/{{$blogs->blogs_file}}" alt=""></td>
                        <td class="sortable">{{$blogs->blogs_title}}</td>
                        <td>{{Illuminate\Support\Str::limit($blogs->blogs_content, 15)}}</td>
                        <td align="center" width="20">
                            <a href="#"><i
                                    class="fa fa-pencil-square"></i></a>
                        </td>
                        <td align="center" width="20">
                            <a href="javascript:void(0)"><i id="{{$blogs->uuid}}"
                                                            class="fa fa-trash-o"></i></a>
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                @endforeach
                </tbody>
```

jquery :

```
$(function () {
            $.ajaxSetup({
                headers: {
                    'X-CSRF-TOKEN': $('meta[name="csrf-token"]').attr('content')
                }
            });
            $('#sortable').sortable({
                revert: true,
                handle: ".sortable",
                stop: function (event, ui) {
                    var data = $(this).sortable('serialize');
                    $.ajax({
                        type: "POST",
                        data: data,
                        url: "{{route('blogs.Sortable')}}",
                        success: function (msg) {

                            if (msg) {
                                alertify.success('İşlem Başarılı');
                            } else {
                                alertify.error('İşlem Başarısız');
                            }
                        }
                    });
                }
            });
            $('#sortable').disableSelection();
        });
```

BlogController:

```
public function sortable()
    {
        foreach ($_POST['item'] as $key => $value) {
            $blogs = Blogs::find(intval($value));
            $blogs->blogs_must = intval($key);
            $blogs->save();
        }
        echo true;
    }
```

In this usage, it work perfectly fine. But when i change
`<tr id="item-{{$blogs->id}}">` to

```
<tr id="item-{{$blogs->uuid}}">
```

it fails.

Comment: What's the error? Using hyphens (ie. the `-` character) is perfectly valid in an `id` attribute and should not cause any problems

Comment: It gives internal server error 500. If i remove hyphens(-) on the uuids, it passes. item-abcd-123-cbd3 gives error. item-abcd123cbs3 passes.

Comment: A 500 error means the problem is in your server side code

Comment: How are you using that reference with the jQuery? ... That could make the difference. As Rory said, that is a valid id as it appears.

Comment: @Paul T. , i will update my post to make it more clear.

Comment: I would suggest using unique IDs, `item-1` and then also add the data attribute: `data-uuid="b20s0b82-dc01-4e9a-a7a6-cd60ff5f9165"`

Comment: Twisty's suggestion was my thought too. Could using `data-uuid` be a possible alternative for the desired handling?

Comment: Thanks guys. All i wanted to do avoid using my primary_key. I decided to open a new row my database table like uniqid. i used to uniqid() function to generate uniqid. Then i update my index.blade like <tr id="item-{{$adminSettings->uniqid}}"> now it works...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

UPDATE: I finally figured it out.The problem coming this part:

> var data = $(this).sortable('serialize');

So if i want to use UUIDs instead of IDs i should do this way:

In the tablebody;

> id="item_{{$blogs->uuid}}"

Than my Jquery code:

> var data = $(this).sortable('serialize',{expression: /(.+)_(.+)/ });

Now it's done.